# javax.naming.CommunicationException When enabling a firewall

Tags: java, jboss, rmi, jndi

I'm getting the following error when i'm trying to connect via RMI to a JBoss application

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer]
```

This error occurs only after enabling IPtables on a linux server.

At the moment, we use this application as a logging tool between 2 servers, but it all Ports to be open because RMI uses random ports for the export of objects if i'm not mistaken

We have tested with some small test applications and the following is a viable solution when using firewalls with RMI:

```
 UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 1244);
```

I export the object over port 1244

The following ports are open at this moment:

1. 1244: The RMI-export object
2. 1066: Binding with RMI on the server
3. 1099: Registering on the management server

Is there anybody that could push me in the right direction to get this implementation working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello EJP, 1066 is being used to create the RMI registry, whereas 1099 is being used to register on the Management server via a JNP url:
properties.put("java.naming.provider.url","jnp://exampleserver:1099");